# Can you hide CSS classes from the properties pane in Dreamweaver CS3?

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there any way to hide or limit the CSS classes available in the Style drop-down box in the Properties pane?

I've got several classes that are used in the header, footer, navigation, or other specialized areas, that shouldn't clutter up someone looking for the few general-use classes available.  I'm afraid after a few months I'll see class="Style22" again.

Dreamweaver CS3 is a requirement, others in the shop use design view (WYSIWYG).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to limit this in Dreamweaver.  However, Contribute can be restricted that way and if you are supporting non-designer/developer end users you may want to look into that.